# How to set FLAG_SUPPORTS_MOVE to Document?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, documentfile

Finally I found out that to move `Document` instances I need to (somehow) set `FLAG_SUPPORTS_MOVE` to it. But `Document` class haven't any `setFlag()` or others methods. I tried set flags to URI with `getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission()` but IDE warns that I use other flags not specified by annotations. I just want to move all files from one folder to other on 25 API.

Answer (score 2):

The client does not set `FLAG_SUPPORTS_MOVE`. The `DocumentsProvider` advertises whether a document can be moved, renamed, etc. using these sorts of flags. If the provider has added that flag, then you can [use `moveDocument()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.html#moveDocument(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.net.Uri)) to move the document from one collection to another within the same provider.

Comment: Am I need to implement my own DocumentProvider? Or is there platform-made provider?

Comment: @constantinopolskaya: "Am I need to implement my own DocumentProvider?" -- probably not. If you could do that, you would have direct filesystem access to whatever it is that you are trying to move, and you would not need any of this. "Or is there platform-made provider?" -- you are already using it, presumably. You have not indicated where this `Uri` is coming from. If it is from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, etc., then that `Uri` was given to you by somebody else's `DocumentProvider`.

Comment: I got URI from SAF (intent action) so where is DocumentProvider? I'm sorry but I'm struggling at all

Comment: @constantinopolskaya: "so where is DocumentProvider?" -- it was developed by some other computer programmer. Depending on which document the user selects, it could be a system-supplied `DocumentProvider`, or one from a non-system app (e.g., Google Drive, other third-party apps). Either that provider adds `FLAG_SUPPORTS_MOVE` to its documents, or it does not.

Comment: @constantinopolskaya The provider is accessible via `ContentResolver` by supplying the Uri. This should probably be added to the documentation of `Uri`…